# Bytes alignment when sending packets

Tags: network-programming, socks

If I send a packet containing address, port and other stuff, would there be any alignment problem on the other side? (using socks 5 protocol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which language you're programming in. If you're using C or C++, there are functions like `htons`, `htonl`, `ntohs`, `ntohl` and more to standardize network data elements into a transportable format. [This guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) (among many others) will tell you how to write network portable code so differences in endianness will not bite you in the @ss.

Comment: yes,i am using c++ i use htons for example when i set the port to initialize the socket,but my packet looks like this: packet[20] how do i set all packet using thoose functions ?

Comment: You have to apply those functions on an item by item basis, to normalize each address, port or whatever in the packet, not the packet as a whole.